# Reading a particular row in a CSV for a given value X, Y returning variable Z

Tags: python, csv

I have three columns in the CSV file storing the value of X, Y, and Z.
These variables are not related by any equation. I want to get the Z value from the given data for Corresponding X and Y values I got from the equations.
Also, the given X and Y values come from different equations. Thus, it sometimes doesn't match the available data. Is there a way I can snap to the closest value available in the data and get the Z value for that?
E.g., this is the data stored in the CSV file.

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -16.332 | 35.523 | 690 |
| -15.523 | 35.567 | 689 |

If I have a given value of -16.331 for X and 35.522 for y, I want the value of Z, which would be 690.

I tried using CSV read. But I don't know how to get the Z data and snap to the closest value.

```
with open('example.csv') as Ex:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(Ex)
    for row in csv_reader:
        X = row[3]
        Y = row[2]
        if X == 12.9165922:
            if Y == 15.2604115:
                (get corresponding Z value)
```

Comment: So what language is this script written in? You probably want to tag that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shortest Euclidean distance:

example.csv

```
X,Y,Z
-16.332,35.523,690
-15.523,35.567,689
```

Code:

```py
import csv

with open('example.csv', newline='') as file:
    # read all the data converting columns to float
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader) # skip header
    data = [(float(x),float(y),float(z)) for x,y,z in reader]

def find_nearest(x,y):
    def euclidean_distance(row):
        return ((x-row[0])**2 + (y-row[1])**2)**.5
    data.sort(key=euclidean_distance)
    # return Z of first row (shortest distance) after sort
    return data[0][2]

print(find_nearest(-16.331,35.522))
```

Output:

```
690
```

Also a `pandas` solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

def find_nearest(x, y):
    # Add/update a column with distance to x,y for each row
    df['dist'] = ((x - df['X'])**2 + (y - df['Y'])**2)**.5
    # return the Z of smallest distance.
    return df.iloc[df.dist.idxmin()].Z

print(find_nearest(-16.331,35.522))
```

Comment: Thanks, mark. This works. But for extensive data and multiple iterations, this will take considerable time to solve. Although I don't have any alternative, so I am using this way. So thank you very much.